# Is there an interesting metric space with a metric which is not induced from a norm?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

Let $S$ be a nonempty set.
Let $d:S\times S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$.
Then, $(S,d)$ is a metric space.

This is the only example of a metric space with a metric which is not induced from a norm I know.

Is there an interesting metric space with a metric which is not induced from a norm?

---

The following is the definition of a norm:

Let $E$ be a vector space. A **norm** on $E$ is a fucntion $v\mapsto|v|$ from $E$ into $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following axioms:
N1. We have $|v|\geq 0$ and $|v|=0$ if and only if $v=0$.
N2. If $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v\in E$, then $|av|=|a||v|$.
N3. For all $v,w\in E$ we have $|v+w|\leq |v|+|w|.$

Comment: How are you defining norm?

Comment: Any of the metrics on the space of random variables that induce convergence in probability. Here it is very nice to know that convergence in probability is a metrizable kind of convergence. Same can be said for many other examples where just knowing that the space is metrizable is useful, whereas the metric itself isn't too important.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you very much for your comment. I edited my question.

Comment: @Mason Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: There are so many. See for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498860/interesting-examples-of-metrics), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1)...

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much for your information.